# Обновление изображения

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброе утро.
Каким образом можно сделать обновление картинки? На сайте выводится капча и нужна функция обновления изображения по нажатию пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в jQuery это так

```
$('img').click(function() {
    var img = $(this).attr('src');

    img += Math.random().toString(36);

    $(this).attr('src', img);

    return false;
})
```